# create events on my Application's page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am in a process of writing an app which works this way
1. Asks a user permission for events_create, publish_stream
2. Gets the access_token for the same
3. takes input of Title, date, time, location( ie all inputs) from a form  and then calls graph api like
/$app_id/events along with access token and post date

I want this to create an event within my APPLICATION's events and hence I use $app_id instead of ..../me/events

But it creates an event on USER's wall ???

I want users to be able to create an event on my wall. It should be an event whose owner is the application and the user should get invited along with his contacts( if he chooses so) ...

Basically, I think POST to /$app_id/events and /me/events work the same, I think it should not ... Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance ..

AC

---

HiShakyeb,

Same result ... It just creates an event in my account rather than the application's.

Here is the code I am using ..

```
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$app/events?" . $access_token; 
    $params = array();
    // Prepare Event fields
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    if(strlen($value))
        $params[$key] = $value;

$params['name']=mysql_real_escape_string($params['name']);
$params['description']=mysql_real_escape_string($params['description']);
$params['location']=mysql_real_escape_string($params['location']);

$params['end_time']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"))); 
$params['privacy_type']="SECRET";

   // Start the Graph API call
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

I also tried just app/events? instead of $app/events?

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: I think my app will need to provide event creation  permission to the user to create event on app page ... it's kind of a reverse permission. I am unaware of how an app provide the user permissions to create events on its page???

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Page Admin access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) to take an action on behalf of that application's page. To do this, get `/me/accounts` with the `manage_pages` permission. That will give you the pages you have access to (including the app's profile page), along with an access token to use for acting as that page/application. If you use that access token, then events will be created as the application page and not the user. See the Graph API documentation for the [Page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP-SDK I uses the api call for **automatic** POSTING an Event in App page **after** filling a form.

Here the automatic process after the user (You) have an valid APP access_token and manage app/page permissions. The token to use is your APP token you receive with your FBapp connection.

## Starting creating php-sdk object

```
$connectparam = array();
$connectparam['appId'] = 'YOURAPPID';
$connectparam['secret'] = 'YOURAPPSECRET';
$connectparam['fileUpload'] = 'true';
$connectparam['cookie'] = 'true';
$facebook = new Facebook($this->connectparam);
```

## Building the event informations

```
$FBcreateAnTestEvent = array();
$nowtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$FBcreateAnTestEvent['name'] = 'Test Event in myApp from me';
$FBcreateAnTestEvent['start_time'] = $nowtime;
$FBcreateAnTestEvent['privacy_type'] = 'SECRET';
$FBcreateAnTestEvent['description'] = 'This Event is created from my WebFBApp and is a testing Event creating by Qtronik from myWebApp';
```

## Automaticly create event

```
$resp = '<a href="'.$facebook->api('/me/events','POST',$FBcreateAnTestEvent).'">
Create a test event</a>';
echo $resp;
```

**When is echoing the php-sdk create immediately the Event so it's better to  put it in a ajax or in action linked page in a form**

### For FanPage use FQL link

If You parse the FBuser admin_pages and filter by **APPLICATION** field and/or filter by your FBpage id you can get this user FBpages admin access_token's. Of Course you need the manage_pages permissions. Then you need **admin_events** permission to publish to FBfanPage's. I create an FanPageEvent with GraphApi link like this:

```
$pageAccessToken = $facebook->api('/' . $YOURPAGEID . '/?fields=access_token');
$resp = '<a href="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$pageAccessToken['id'].'/events
?access_token=' . $pageAccessToken['access_token'] . '
&method=POST
&name='.$FBcreateAnTestEvent['name'].'
&start_time='.$FBcreateAnTestEvent['start_time'].'
&location='.$FBcreateAnTestEvent['location'].')">
Create a test event</a>';
```

Then voila I have allot of other things to do with this for handle it with Ajax but this is the two way of adding an Event's to Facebook from a website administrating way... All this it's not very intended for personal profile event create so it's more difficult to spam FBpages and or FBapp/FBwebapp.

> I'm French speaking so excuse my poor English... ;)

Comment: Hey I remember stopping smoke cigarette exactly on this day ! 3 Jan ! Still not smoking and still adding Facebook Event on my website and manipulate OpenGraph stuff too.